# How do i compare a String out of a list in Jinja2 to another string?

Tags: jinja2, python-3.7

I'm using a for loop and inside that forloop i generate tables out of DataBase data.
The thing is that i need to show multiple tables, but the if statement in Jinja2 doesn't seem to work for some reason. I need to check if the string on index 2 of my_list[2] is equal to the 'None'.

{% if '{{my_list[2]}}' == 'None' %}
   There is no connection. 
{% else %}
   There is a GOOD connection.
{% endif %}

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 0):

{% if not customer_list[2] %}

This does exactly wat i needed.